# Hide sender and recipient from a transaction

Tags: transactions, token-2022

I want to make a payment in USDC and hide the sender and recipient of the transaction. If I got it right, this is a functionality that Polygon has implemented with Nightfall.

Can I do that on Solana as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible on Solana. However, [Token Extensions](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022#motivation) (aka Token 2022) allows confidential transfers for mints that have this feature enabled. Confidential transfers only allow to encrypt the amount sent but not the sender or receiver.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Do you know by any chance if there is a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I am not a runtime expert but my understanding is that it's not possible at all at the moment. The main reason being that all transactions must declare the writable accounts, so hiding the sender/receiver would mean encrypting these accounts and I don't think the runtime would be able to handle this.